# Как в C++ Builder убрать стандартное popup меню в компоненте TStringGrid?

Tags: c++, c++builder, popupmenu, stringgrid

На форме проекта есть таблица. В её настройках выставлено свойство goEditing в true. Этой таблице присвоено самописное popupmenu. При выборе ячейки и нажатии правой кнопки мыши вызывается именно оно - на этом этапе всё в порядке. Но после двойного клика мыши по выбранной ячейке и нажатию правой кнопкой мыши вызывается стандартное (если его так можно назвать) контекстное меню вид которого привожу на картинке.

[image: То самое меню]

Пытался в ивенте ContextPopup таблицы присвоить Handled  значение true после вызова своего popupmenu , но это не помогает.

Как убрать возможность вызова этого меню?